# Generating a Key from the first 10 Characters of a Base64 String

Tags: java, base64, aes

Let's say I have a Base64 String:

```
data = AOUTl5C2QV2xFRPlzKR0Ag==
```

I want to generate a Key in Java (Android) from the first 10 characters of this Base64 String and then use it to AES-Decrypt a Message sent from the Server. To do this, I use the below code:

```
String firstTen = data.substring(0, 10);
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(firstTen, Base64.DEFAULT);
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Message_to_Decrypt, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

But then I can a Java.security.Exception:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
```

Is there a way that I can get a valid Key which I can use for AES decryption from the first 10 Characters of a Base64String?

Comment: What class is Base64? There is no Base64.DEFAULT in java.util.Base64 or org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.

Comment: I am doing this in Android

Comment: developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: You can't really Base64 decode 10 characters, Base64 encodings are always a multiple of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the 10 characters with a hash function or better yet PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2).

You really need to provide a key of an expected length, AES keys can be 128, 192 or 256 bytes long. While some AED implementations may null pad the key do not rely on that, it is not part of the standard.

Comment: Google "Java PBKDF2". PBKDF1 [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Answer (score 1):

The error message says: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.

You are using 10 Characters, each char is 8 bits. So 10*8=80. Try with 16 characters (128/8=16).

Comment: but I do not have 16 characters, is there a parameter that I can pass so that it will be automatically extended to 16 Characters, I am told that I need to use the first 10 characters only

Comment: You are trying to decrypt something that is already encrypted, so you cant just make up rules for the key. You probably need to check with who is doing the encryption if they are padding the key or something else.